# SelBlocks extension for Selenium IDE Error

Tags: selenium-ide

i m using sel blocks extension for selenium to carry out the Data Driven Tetsing using xml file.
Whenever i execute the forXml command in Selenium IDE, i m getting the following error:

[error] Unexpected Exception: fileName -> chrome://selblocks/content/extensions/sel-blocks.js?1372683973921, lineNumber -> 739, columnNumber -> 2

Please help me out

thanks,
satish

Comment: So what's on line 739 of `sel_blocks.js?1372683973921`?

Comment: @Simon, i couldn't find the sel-blocks.js file?

Answer (score 1):

Sel Blocks 1.3 is not compatible with Firefox 22. You can install the new version 1.3.1 directly from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-sel-blocks/versions/

Cheers, Samit Badle

Selenium IDE Maintainer. Twitter: @samitbadle Blog: http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/